# como faço uma função de estrutura de repetição no R?

Tags: r, loop, for

estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
 H <- function(n) {

   for (i in 1:length(n))
   {
   x <- 0
   a <- 2
   b <- 3
   func = x + a/b
   a+2
   b+2
   return(func)
   }
 }
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 4):

Eis cinco formas de resolver o problema.

## 1. Com ciclo `while`

```
H1 <- function(n){
  numer <- 2L
  denom <- 3L
  termos <- 0L
  total <- 0L
  while(termos < n){
    total <- total + numer/denom
    numer <- numer + 2L
    denom <- denom + 2L
    termos <- termos + 1L
  }
  total
}
H1(4)
#[1] 3.212698
```

## 2. Com ciclo `for`

```
H2 <- function(n){
  total <- 0
  for(i in seq_len(n)){
    total <- total + 2*i/(2*i + 1L)
  }
  total
}
H2(4)
#[1] 3.212698
```

## 3. Com ciclo `*apply`.

```
H3 <- function(n){
  x <- sapply(seq_len(n), function(i) 2*i/(2*i + 1L))
  sum(x)
}
H3(4)
#[1] 3.212698
```

## 4. Vetorizada

Esta é a melhor maneira, a mais correta uma vez que o R é uma linguagem vetorizada. Primeiro cria dois vetores, um de números pares (os numeradores das frações) e o outro de números ímpares (os denominadores). Depois, com uma única instrução, calcula todas as frações e soma os resultados. Como essa é a última instrução, será o valor de saída da função.

```
H <- function(n){
  pares <- seq(2, by = 2, length.out = n)
  impares <- seq(3, by = 2, length.out = n)
  sum(pares/impares)
}
H(4)
#[1] 3.212698
```

## 5. Outra função vetorizada.

E agora numa só linha.

```
H <- function(n) sum(2*seq_len(n)/(2*seq_len(n) + 1))
H(4)
#[1] 3.212698
```